# keep getting this error "dynamic method [java.util.HashMap, add/1] not found" in kibana console

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am new to elasticsearch stack ... Whenever i try to execute below query in Kibana Dev Tool Console keep getting below mentioned error

- Query Executed in Kibana Console

```
POST employees-details/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "EmpName": "Arvind"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.Address.add(params.tag)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "tag":{
        "AddressID":144,
        "AddressNumber":458
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> keep Getting this error`\/` while executing above query ^^

```
"caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "dynamic method [java.util.HashMap, add/1] not found"
    }
```

- Sample Data

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "employees-details",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "101",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "EmpUserID" : 101,
          "Gender" : "Male",
          "EmpName" : "John",
          "Age" : 35
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "employees-details",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "106",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "EmpUserID" : 106,
          "Address" : {
            "AddressNumber" : 201,
            "AddressID" : 200
          },
          "Gender" : "Male",
          "EmpName" : "Arvind",
          "Age" : 30
        }
      }
]
```

- Versions Used

> kibana : 7.9.3
> elasticsearch : 7.9.3

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Address` is a hash, you cannot use the `add()` method (meant for collections like array, list, etc). Instead you need to transform `Address` to a list first and then call `add()`:

```
POST employees-details/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "EmpName": "Arvind"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "if (!(ctx._source.Address instanceof Collection)) {ctx._source.Address = [ctx._source.Address];} ctx._source.Address.add(params.tag)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "tag":{
        "AddressID":144,
        "AddressNumber":458
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks it is worked. but it is replacing new value with previous value

Comment: And what do you want to do instead?

Comment: want to have both value new added and previous one

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the logic